# Will it work to sort an array in O(n) when an element occurs more than n / 2 times?

Tags: algorithm, runtime

Assuming the comparison of elements in array takes O(n), would it be possible to sort the array in O(n) if an element occurs more than n / 2 times?

Actually it should be possible because there is this median algorithm which will find the middle value of an array, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Assume the smallest element in the array occurs more than `n / 2` times, let's say `ceil(n / 2) + 1`. Then there are still `n - (ceil(n / 2) + 1) ~ n / 2 = O(n)` elements to be sorted, which still takes `O(n log n)` time.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Even if an element occurs more than `n/999` times, the complexity is not `O(n)` because sorting the remaining elements is still `O(n log n)`.

The complexity does not tell you how much time you algorithm will take to complete, it is an indication to how much this time will change when you change `n`, even if the factor of this change is small.

However, *some* distributions *can* influence complexity, for example if you know that only `m` values are allowed (then a`O(n)` algorithm consists in using registers to count the occurrences of each allowed value).